# My facebook app canvas page is showing 'Sorry, this content isn't available right now', why?

Tags: facebook, facebook-graph-api, facebook-apps

I am developing a facebook app, it was working fine, but suddenly it is showing 'Sorry, this content isn't available right now' in everypage of my app. I do not understand why. [Here is the picture of error message.](https://i.stack.imgur.com/aI5ie.png)

Answer (score 1):

This is a current bug: https://developers.facebook.com/bugs/241866786181307

(As a temporary workaround, specify an app namespace, as it says in the response from FB.)